# Can you filter characters (even duplicated) from an array?

Tags: javascript

```js
const stringConvert = string => {
  let splitString = string.split("");
  let vowels = splitString.filter(letters => {
    return letters === "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
  })
  return console.log(vowels);
};


stringConvert("Why don't you try and split this string into vowels, please?");
```

The code above comes back undefined and I am trying to create a function that takes a string and counts how many vowels are in it. So far I have used the .split() to create an array with each individual character of the string and then I tried using .filter() to filter out each character that is a vowel.

What (only vanilla javascript) would allow me to filter out each vowel from an array, so then I could use .length on that array to get the number of vowels?

Comment: you are returning the result from console.log which is undefined. Why not return `vowels` instead?

Comment: That's not how you compare to multiple values. Your `return` statement is equivalent to `return (letters === "a"), "e", "i", "o", "u"`. And due to the way the comma operator works, that's equivalent to `return "u";` Use `return ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(letters);`

Comment: Also, `console.log()` just prints its argument, it doesn't return it. That's why the function returns `undefined`.

Comment: I've removed the remote link and placed your code in a snippet so we can 'run' it without leaving SO. This creates a [mre] that makes a question easier to answer. If you have any other questions about asking here on SO, consider reading [ask] and [tour].

Comment: @Barmar I have done that and it doesn't do anything at all. Could you complete that in jsbin and send it in the comments?

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8yLrcg15/1/

Comment: `[...string].filter(letter => 'aeiou'.includes(letter.toLowerCase())).length` Is probably what you want.

Comment: @Barmar wow thanks man! I'm quite new to JS so could you please explain to me how include() does this? From my research include() only returns a boolean, while filter() actually filters the elements based on the condition, so why do I need include()? Thanks

Comment: `filter()` filters based on a boolean, and `includes()` returns that boolean. It sounds like you didn't see that `includes()` is being used in the condition.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because although the duplicate shows one approach, it's not the only way -- especially when dealing with strings and upper/lowercase.

Comment: @Barmar I thought the `return` itself would return the result of `filter()` to the function, returning all the vowels to the variable. So you have to use `.include()` also?

Comment: My use of `return ...includes()` is in the exact same place as your `return letters === "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"` and serves the same purpose. I'm not sure what's confusing you about what gets returned.

Comment: @Barmar `includes()` : Check if an array contains the specified element `filter()` : Creates a new array with every element in an array that pass a test... my confusion is, if filter already creates a new array with every element that passes this test: `return letters === ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]` then why do we have to use `include` after that test is done and the elements are already passed? Sorry man like I said I'm new to all this

Comment: Your test is wrong, that's the first thing I said. I replaced that test with one that uses `includes()`.

Comment: `letters === ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]` will never be true. `letters` is a string, `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]` is an array, they can never be equal to each other.

Comment: @Barmar I recognize my test was wrong but I just wanted to understand why `includes()` has to be added in when, to me, `filter()` seems to do the whole job by definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243907/discussion-between-jordantocode11-and-barmar).

Comment: There's two things being done: `includes()` tests if an individual letter is a vowel. `filter()` returns all the letters for which this test is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
const stringConvert = string => {
  let splitString = string.split("");
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  let letters = {};
  splitString.forEach(l => {
    letters[l] = letters[l] ? letters[l] + 1 : 1;
  })
  let vowelsCount = [];
  vowels.forEach(l => vowelsCount[l] = letters[l]);
  return vowelsCount;
};
stringConvert("Why don't you try and split this string into vowels, please?");
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question about getting the count of each vowel separately. They just want an array of all the vowels, and then they can use `.length` to get the total count.